# post JsonObject As real php class object to method symfony 4

Tags: json, object, parameters, action, symfony4

hi I want to post json string with programs like postman and then the Action method get parameter without manually convert that !
WebApi can do that very simple !

```
class User
{
    private $FirstName;
    private $LastName;
    private $Age;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->FirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $FirstName
     */
    public function setFirstName(string $FirstName): void
    {
        $this->FirstName = $FirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->LastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $LastName
     */
    public function setLastName(string $LastName): void
    {
        $this->LastName = $LastName;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->Age;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $Age
     */
    public function setAge(int $Age): void
    {
        $this->Age = $Age;
    }



}
```

then in controller class on method like setUser get the deserialized value of json passed with postman . I don't like to user Request class instead of my object .

```
/**
 * @Route("/setUser/",methods={"POST"})
 * @param User $user
 * @return Response
 */
public function setUser(User $user)
{
    return new Response("Age is: " . $user->getAge());
}
```

when send with postman value of $user parameter is null !

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to transform an input JSON into an object? If It is that, take a look at the Serializer component -> http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: @DayronGallardo i want to send json with postman and then in setUser function get converted object without add code ! Automatically do that and get me user object.

Comment: I don't think you can do that such a thing without coding. On my knowledge, in Symfony, you can't do autobind of input data (JSON or form for example) to an entity. You need to code a class for bind your input data to the entity.

Comment: @DayronGallardo so Symfony confusing me! Webapi do that without coding.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned about a bundle that you can integrate very easy in a Symfony 4 project that makes just what you want -> https://api-platform.com/ . Once installed, you only need to care about the Entity definitions. This bundle generates the endpoint for the API methods and handle de CRUD.

Comment: thanks but switch to Spring boot and so so so much happy now . beacuse I'm Android iOS Developer And spring language is java ! now Spring can convert json Object to model even better than any api I seen ever !